# Document preview library in JavaScript/rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, preview

Is there any JavaScript/rails library/gem/plug-in to preview document(.doc, pdf, xls and most common doc types) on web page?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla is working on a [PDF renderer written in JavaScript](https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js). For other common types, you can convert them to PDF format on the server side using OpenOffice/LibreOffice by installing the `cups-pdf` virtual printer and then print your document via OpenOffice:

```
oowriter -pt pdf your_word_file.doc
```

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux).